# click "checkout with paypal" in magento to open new window

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.4

Paypal wont open in an iframe, so I am trying to make paypal open in a new window or tab when the checkout with paypal button is pressed, using Magento 1.4+

I guess I add a target="_blank" somewhere, but I dont know where.

There are a load of files in \app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\ but I dont know which to edit, adn would prefer to do it without using core files

I found this for paypal express in  app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Block\Express\Shortcut.php

```
protected $_startAction = 'paypal/express/start';
```

How would I just open that in a new window?

Comment: is this a good idea, because when Paypal redirects back to your site, you will have two instances of it running, and this is not ideal for customer experience.

Comment: paypal not opening in an iframe also is not ideal for customer experience.  I mean using paypal at all is not ideal, but it seems if you want to use a paypal button to paypal express from a iframe, opening a new window is the way.  Id be happy if you had another way to get paypal to work?

Comment: We use it without using an iframe, but we just tell them (the 5 customers who has not used it yet) that they will get redirected to paypal, and then back. Same with Google checkout. if pop-ups are blocked, then you might have a non working system, if you try a new window.

Comment: i need to use it within an iframe.  It must be inside an iframe.  Again I need this because the function I am using it for is within an iframe.  I have found no way that Paypal Express can open in an iframe.  I have a non working system.  A non working system only if popups are blocked is preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Paul - I did this instead to the same file and it worked!

Change (my line 33)

```
<a id="<?php echo $shortcutHtmlId ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl()?>">
```

to

```
<a id="<?php echo $shortcutHtmlId ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl()?>" target="_blank">
```

Easy but wouldn't have done it without Paul's help

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question yourself, we first need to know how the button is rendered on the website.

We first need to know which template is used and if we really need to digg deep, find out which Block is used to render the template.

Enable `Template hints` in `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug` or download the excellent [Advanced Template Hints Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-template-hints.html) and just add `?ath=1` for the URL you are trying to view template hints for.

Now when you are viewing the page with the template hints you should see that the PayPal button is rendered with using `frontend/base/default/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml`.

Open up that file, start browsing in `/yourmagentoinstallation/app/design/`, you'll find the `frontend/` folder there.

Now we can see what is going on in that template, we can see that this templates adds an `<a>, <span>, <input>` and a bit of javascript:

```
//<![CDATA[
    Event.observe('<?php echo $shortcutHtmlId ?>', 'click', function(event) {
        <?php if ($this->getConfirmationUrl()): ?>
            if (confirm('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->getConfirmationMessage())?>')) {
                this.href = '<?php echo $this->getConfirmationUrl() ?>';
            }
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->getIsInCatalogProduct()): ?>
            $('pp_checkout_url').value = this.href;
            productAddToCartForm.submit(this);
            event.stop();
        <?php endif; ?>
    });
//]]>
```

Here we set the href of the form to post to, since there is no real link that we can change, we need to set the target of the form to blank, we can do this with javascript:

Put:

`productAddToCartForm.setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Above:

`productAddToCartForm.submit(this);`

Comment: thanks for the link to the hints module & great explanation.  But after making the changes, it still opens in same window.  1.4 has no this in productAddToCartForm.submit();  I dont know if that makes a diff?    <?php if ($this->getIsInCatalogProduct()): ?>
            $('pp_checkout_url').value = this.href;
            productAddToCartForm.submit();
            event.stop();
        <?php endif; ?>